# Creating a macro in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have this piece of code. I want to create a macro

```
create_table(:some_table) do
  primary_key :id

  # should be generated by macro
  DateTime :inserted_at
  DateTime :updated_at
end
```

How can I create such a macro that generates those 2 lines of code so that I can do this:

```
create_table(:some_table) do
  primary_key :id

  # should be generated by macro
  my_macro_that_generates_timestamps()
end
```

Comment: Ruby does not have macros. If you're using Rails, please include the appropriate tag.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo "*Ruby does not have macros*" - super confusing, because a web search yields many resources stating otherwise. Example: "*Macros are everywhere in Ruby. You cannot get very far into the Ruby language without encountering a Macro.*" from [here](https://www.bigbinary.com/books/learn-rubyonrails-book/rails-macros-and-metaprogramming).

Comment: @stevec Interesting. That article calls things like `attr_accessor` and `belongs_to` macros. Given that those have applicative-order evaluation of arguments and could easily be written in Ruby as ordinary functions, I have to disagree with calling them "macros". In most languages, a macro is distinct from a function and doesn't evaluate its arguments, instead giving the macro body an abstract syntax tree and returning an abstract syntax tree as a result. Lisp, Rust, Elixir, Scala, and Factor, off the top of my head, all use this definition. So I stand by my claim that Ruby does not have them.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo if I understand correctly, it sounds like although ruby has a construct the ruby world (or part of it) refers to as macros, those same constructs aren't macros in the broader programming sense (i.e. in the sense that someone who codes in Lisp, for example, would call a macro).

Comment: @stevec I'm inclined to agree with that summary. Ruby is free to call the feature what it likes, and although I disagree with the use of that term, I can't argue that it does seem to be in use in the Ruby community.

Answer (score 4):

If you know what class this is, you can patch in any method you want. If you don't know what class it is you can always find out using the caveman method of *breaking things*:

```
create_table(:some_table) do
  raise self.class.to_s
end
```

Now you get an exception and hopefully some insight. Once you know that, you can add methods to it:

```
class MigrationClass
  def timestamps_as_usual
    DateTime :inserted_at
    DateTime :updated_at
  end
end
```

Where if you've matched the *context* correctly then that code should work with that name.

There's no macro needed here, just a simple method call.

```
create_table(:some_table) do
  primary_key :id

  timestamps_as_usual
end
```

Comment: I'm not asking whether the macros is needed or not. I'm asking -- how to do that with a macros!

Comment: @Kakki Honestly, nobody cares what you were asking in a nutshell. This site is created for and driven by future visitors. We are producing a knowledge base, that could help people coming later. This is a perfect and enduring answer, specifically taking into account that the correct answer to what you were saying is “there are no macros in ruby, period.”

Comment: @Kakki In most languages "macro" means "bit of code executed before compilation in order to rewrite how the code is interpreted by the compiler" but Ruby has no such phase. Since Ruby is a dynamic language, macro-type code and runtime code are the same thing. Macros become method calls, that's all. Meta-programming, as in methods that generate code, are a first-class feature of the language.

Comment: @Kakki As such, the answer here is to just define a method that, when called, does whatever you want. In C you'd need a macro, the compiler needs to know exactly what code you're calling in advance. In Ruby you don't, you can change your method definitions any time.